# How to pause a video when mouse is taken off?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I was messing around to find a way to pause or mute a video, if we take off our cursor from it with using HTML5 and CSS3 only.But i was unable to find a way.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: I really doubt it. But it's straightforward with a bit of JS. See Gaby aka G. Petrioli's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/0o8tt2z8/1/) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26779453/1693947)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery and HTML5 video, you could do something like:

```
var vid = $(".myVideo"); 
vid.mouseleave(function() {
    vid.pause()
});
```

Then, when you want to play again,

```
vid.mouseenter(function() {
    vid.play()
});
```

The functions vid.play() and vid.pause() are built in so this shouldn't give you any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
<div id="video-wrapper">
    <video id="v" src="video.mp4" controls></video>
</div>
```

Getting video element using jQuery:

```
   var v = $("#v");
```

Check if video is ready to play:

```
  $(v).on('canplay', function(){
      $(v).mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).get(0).play();
      }).mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).get(0).pause();
      })
   });
```