# Play multiple Plyr Vimeo embeds on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plyr.js

I have multiple videos embedded on a page with [Plyr.js](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr). My end goal is to get each video to play on hover and stop when there is no hover.

Here is my current code:

```js
const players = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#player')).map(p => new Plyr(p, {
  debug: true,
  volume: 0,
  controls: false,
  muted: true,
  fullscreen: { enabled: false },
  loop: { active: true },
  duration: 10
}));

$('#player').hover(playVideo, pauseVideo);
function playVideo(e){$(players, this).get(0).play();}
function pauseVideo(e){$(players, this).get(0).pause();}
```

```css
.plyr{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.4.7/plyr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player" class="plyr__video-embed">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/298038460?loop=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&transparent=0" allowtransparency></iframe>
</div>
<div id="player" class="plyr__video-embed">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/298038460?loop=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&transparent=0" allowtransparency></iframe>
</div>
```

The code above plays only the first video on hover but does not play other videos.

If anyone has any suggestions please feel free to share. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have two `id="player"`. `id` should be unique in HTML. Replace it with `class` and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is the duplicate `id` values. They need to be unique. You already have a class (*`.plyr__video-embed`*) for those elements so use that instead.

Your `hover` methods also try to find the player inside the hovered element, but that will not work because `players` array holds instances of the player plugin and not DOM nodes.

So just find the `index` of the hovered element (*amongst the player nodes*) and use it to access the relevant player.

```js
const playerNodes = $('.plyr__video-embed');
const players = playerNodes.map((i,p) => new Plyr(p, {
  debug: true,
  volume: 0,
  controls: false,
  muted: true,
  fullscreen: { enabled: false },
  loop: { active: true }
})).get();

playerNodes.hover(playVideo, pauseVideo);

function playVideo(e){players[playerNodes.index(this)].play();}
function pauseVideo(e){players[playerNodes.index(this)].pause();}
```

```css
.plyr {
  display: inline-block;
}

.plyr__video-embed {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plyr/3.4.7/plyr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plyr__video-embed">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/298038460?loop=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&transparent=0" allowtransparency></iframe>
</div>
<div class="plyr__video-embed">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/298038460?loop=1&byline=0&portrait=0&title=0&transparent=0" allowtransparency></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply Gabriele! Your solution worked!

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution. It's working smoothly for embedded video but I'm a bit curious why it's not working for html5 videos.

Comment: @JilaniA Could you post an example (or even better a new question) with your code that is not working ?

Comment: Dear Gabriele Petrioli, thank you so much for your quick response :) kindly check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77788363/plyr-multiple-players-play-on-hover-and-pause-when-mouse-out