# Plyr multiple players play on hover and pause when mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, video-player, plyr.js

I'm following this overflow discussion ( [Play multiple Plyr Vimeo embeds on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585355/play-multiple-plyr-vimeo-embeds-on-hover/53585805) ) this solution perfectly working for embedded videos (YouTube, Vimeo etc) unfortunately not working for HTML5 videos.

In an Ajax query, I'm fetching videos ( video player could be HTML, YouTube, Vimeo or others ) In this query embedded video (YouTube and Vimeo) working on hover but HTML is not.

Here is the section screenshot you might check https://prnt.sc/lYc5q8kIDvb8
first 3 HTML video players ( not working on mouse hover ) and the last 3 YouTube and Vimeo players ( working fine on mouse hover ).

Here is my JS code below -

```
    <?php $attr['section_id'] = 1; ?>

    <div class="video-load-more-content-<?php echo esc_attr( $attr['section_id'] ); ?> row"></div>
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 pagination text-center">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="vidiow-primary" id="load-more-<?php echo esc_attr( $attr['section_id'] ); ?>" data-action="vidiow_load_more<?php echo esc_attr( $attr['section_id'] ); ?>">Load more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        ;(function ($) {
    
            'use strict';
    
            $(document).ready(function () {
    
                let paged = 0;
                let $buttonSelector = $('#load-more-<?php echo esc_attr( $attr['section_id'] ); ?>');
                let $content = $('.video-load-more-content-<?php echo esc_attr( $attr['section_id'] ); ?>');
    
                $buttonSelector.on('click', function(e) {
    
                    if (e.preventDefault) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
    
                    paged++; // Do currentPage + 1, because we want to load the next page
    
                    $buttonSelector.text('Loading ...');
    
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )); ?>',
                        dataType: 'json', // <-- Change dataType from 'html' to 'json'
                        data: {
                            action: $buttonSelector.data('action'),
                            nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'vidiow_ajax_load_more' ); ?>',
                            paged,
                            action_name: $buttonSelector.data('action')
                        },
    
                        success: function (response) {
    
                            if(paged >= response.max) {
                                $buttonSelector.hide();
                            }
                            $content.append(response.content);
                            $buttonSelector.text('Load More');
    
                            /**
                             * Video player initialization
                             */
                            const playerNodes = $('.vidiow_player');
                            const vidiow_player = playerNodes.map(
                                (currentValue, index, arr) => new Plyr( index, {
                                    debug: true,
                                    ratio: '16:9',
                                    volume: 0,
                                    controls: false,
                                    muted: true,
                                    fullscreen: { enabled: false },
                                    loop: { active: true }
                                })
                            ).get();
    
                            if( vidiow_player ){
                                vidiow_player.forEach(( player, index ) =>
                                    player.on("play", () =>
                                        vidiow_player
                                        .filter((p, i) => i !== index)
                                        .forEach((p) => p.pause())
                                    )
                                );
                            }
    
                            playerNodes.hover(playVideo, pauseVideo);
    
                            function playVideo(e){
                                vidiow_player[playerNodes.index(this)].play();
                            }
    
                            function pauseVideo(e){
                                vidiow_player[playerNodes.index(this)].pause();
                            }
    
                            // Initialize bootstrap tooltip
                            $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    
                        }
                    });
                });
    
                $buttonSelector.trigger('click');
    
            });
    
        })(jQuery);
    
    </script>
```

HTML code -

```
<!-- Youtube -->
<div class="plyr__video-embed vidiow_player">
    <iframe
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_video_url ); ?>?origin=https://plyr.io&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"
        allowfullscreen
        allowtransparency
        allow="autoplay">
    </iframe>
</div>

<!-- HTML 5-->
<video class="vidiow_player" playsinline controls data-poster="img.jpg">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

*Another crucial issue I'm facing in the Ajax process is Plyr, masonry or others need reinitialization inside jQuery "success: function (response)" which is already initialized in the main JS code. Only the first load main js code works but doesn't work when clicking on Ajax action.*

**Note: If you need any more information to make smooth the answering process, please inform me.**

Comment: It seems to be working just fine in https://jsfiddle.net/wvfyntzb/. Where are you running your code ? Is the server correctly setup up to allow serving .mp4 files ?

Comment: I'm working on the XAMPP server for WordPress. I see it's working on jsfiddle. Yes, mp4 works on the server when I click but not working on hover. I am initializing players through Ajax. I mean when Ajax succeeds, player js code starts work. Could it be an issue?

Comment: The ajax thing could be an issue depending on how it is implemented. Could you post the loading code and how/when you run the plyr code ?

Comment: I've updated the question :) I didn't include the PHP process. If you need please inform me.

Comment: I've got the issue. It's conflicting with plyr.css
Add the plyr style <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.7.8/plyr.css" />
the problem will appear.

Comment: Updated my answer to deal with the css issue. demo at https://jsfiddle.net/cny8apr7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update #2**

Since the plyr plugin alters the DOM, it is not possible to dynamically extract the player instances from there, for embedded videos. So a different approach is to have a global `Map` to store t
he players linked to their original element. Then you can search in there for all your actions.

```js
;
(function($) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function() {

    const AllVideos = new Map();

    let paged = 0;
    let $buttonSelector = $('#load-more-<?php echo esc_attr( $attr['section_id'] ); ?>');
    let $content = $('.video-load-more-content-<?php echo esc_attr( $attr['section_id'] ); ?>');

    $buttonSelector.on('click', function(e) {

      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      paged++; // Do currentPage + 1, because we want to load the next page

      $buttonSelector.text('Loading ...');

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )); ?>',
        dataType: 'json', // <-- Change dataType from 'html' to 'json'
        data: {
          action: $buttonSelector.data('action'),
          nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'vidiow_ajax_load_more' ); ?>',
          paged,
          action_name: $buttonSelector.data('action')
        },

        success: function(response) {

          if (paged >= response.max) {
            $buttonSelector.hide();
          }
          $content.append(response.content);
          $buttonSelector.text('Load More');

          /**
           * Video player initialization
           */
          const newPlayerNodes = $('.vidiow_player')
            .filter((index, element) => !element.plyr);

          const new_vidiow_players = newPlayerNodes.map(
            (index, element, arr) => {
              const player = new Plyr(element, {
                debug: true,
                ratio: '16:9',
                volume: 0,
                controls: false,
                muted: true,
                fullscreen: {
                  enabled: false
                },
                loop: {
                  active: true
                }
              });
              AllVideos.set(element, player);
              return player;
            }
          ).get();

          if (new_vidiow_players.length) {
            new_vidiow_players.forEach((player) =>
              player.on("play", () => {
                [...AllVideos.values()]
                .filter((p) => p !== player)
                  .forEach((p) => p.pause())
              })
            );
          }

          newPlayerNodes.hover(playVideo, pauseVideo);

          function playVideo(e) {
            AllVideos.get(this).play();
          }

          function pauseVideo(e) {
            AllVideos.get(this).pause();
          }
          // Initialize bootstrap tooltip
          $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

        }
      });
    });

    $buttonSelector.trigger('click');

  });

})(jQuery);
```

**Update #1**

after the comment about the css, the issue is that the `hover` is applied on the actual video element but the poster is positioned on top of it, so the video does not receive the `hover` event and the code never runs.

If you add a css rule `.plyr__poster{ pointer-events: none; }` it should fix it.

The original answer might still help avoid some issues in the future, by just initializing the new elements.

Comment: Thank you so much, dear Gabriele Petrioli :)

I'm very pleased with your explanation. Certainly, I'm struggling to avoid multiple Plyr instances throughout the website including the jQuery success function. I love to use only one instance throughout the website. Unfortunately, I'm not getting any solution for this. Still, I'm acquiring JS knowledge. 

If you have any idea about that point never forget to share it with us.

Comment: It's ( Original ) appearing - TypeError Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'play') Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pause')

Comment: @JilaniA right, the `playVideo` and `pauseVideo` have a stale version of  `allPlayerNodes`. Updated answer.

Comment: @JilaniA rewrote the answer with a different approach, since the Plyr plugin is modifying the DOM and i do not know where they store the instance of the player.

Comment: Thank you so much Gabriele, really learned a lot from you.

Comment: One more thing still I'm curious. Can I get rid of multiple Plyr instances? I just want to use a single instance throughout the website/page including Ajax load and want to store this code inside only the main js file.

Comment: @JilaniA you are welcome. Regarding the single Plyr instance, i do not think that the plyr.js library supports this. All the initialization methods returns an array of instances..

Comment: Yeah got the point!