# Play selected video on mouse cursor over / Pause when cursor off

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm venturing into HTML5 and JavaScript but would really appreciate some pointers on how I could achieve the following: I'm trying to help users with limited abilities/movement to select and play a video (in a web browser on a windows desktop computer) simply by putting the mouse cursor over the video - this will either be by using a physical mouse, tapping on the video (to effectively place the cursor over the video) or via an EyeGaze (Eye tracking) type system.

Essentially I would like to have two or four video thumbnails (of approx. 600x400 dimensions - large enough to give the user a cause and effect experience and to gauge what they like or motivates them) neatly displayed evenly on a screen with no buttons to distract the user. The user would then simply move the mouse cursor over the video they desire and the video will automatically start to play and when the mouse cursor is moved away from the video the video will pause.

Thanks for reading. Hope somebody can help with that.

Many thanks

Comment: Please share what code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please can a moderator delete my question. I think I just found what I need ([Video play on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778714/video-play-on-hover))

Thanks and sorry!